# LibreOffice: Make all references in selection absolute

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Suppose I have a range of cells which contain relative references in localc. Is there a quick way to select this range and change every reference to an absolute one i.e. adding Dollar signs in each reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the cells you want to change. Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>F4</kbd> to cycle through the different forms of reference, `A1` → `$A$1` → `A$1` → `$A1` → `A1`. This changes all cells in the selected range.

This works with non-contiguous ranges too. Tested on LibreOffice 3.4.5 on Linux and 3.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

In LibreOffice 5.4.6.2, this can be done much simpler. Just select the Area and click Sheet → Cycle Cell Reference Types (Shortcut: <kbd>F4</kbd>)